# Check SQL Server table every month

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I need to check entries in a database every month to see if they have been updated. For example, an entry would look something like this:

```
id   timestamp     completed
123  12-AUG-2011      N
```

I need to check to see if the entries in this table have been 'completed' within 30 days of their timestamp. I then need to send an e-mail to specified person who can then handle the ageing entry.

Is there a way to achieve this using just C# (Visual Studio 2010) and SQL Server 2008? Scripts are disallowed on this particular server I am working with so I'm hoping there is an alternate solution.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say scripts are disallowed what exactly does that mean? Are you allowed to schedule jobs through SQL server agent?

Comment: I can't schedule scripts on this server, it has been disabled (like Perl scripts). I haven't used jobs in SQL Server Agent before, would that be the best route?

Comment: With SQL agent, you can schedule a specific set of SQL statements to run periodically.

Comment: Please note that if you have 'timestamps' with data from every day of the month, you will have to check the table every _day_, not every _month_ as you state.  Otherwise, some entries may be left for 60+ days, not the 30 you presume; actually, you have to do it every day anyways, if you're looking for 30 days precisely, and not '1 month'.

Comment: Yeah, what I meant to say was that I needed to check every day for entries that are a month old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on what version or configuration of SQL server your host has but you may be able to schedule jobs to run through SQL server agent.

Here's a [HOWTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx)

Comment: Note that most providers of shared SQL Server hosting are not going to provide access to SQL Server Agent. Something to check on, for sure, but don't get your hopes up. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a very simple Windows Service to run at whichever time interval you require.
So say every month it would tick and dispatch an event to perform the checking and email if needed and when finished set the interval again to the next month. This way you could expand easily enough at a later point.

If you've not done a service before then this [article](http://en.csharp-online.net/Creating_a_.NET_Windows_Service) might be a nice start.

Hope that helps.

Paul